# Pydantic create model for list with nested dictionary

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a body looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "my_api": {
          "label": "First name",
          "value": "Micheal"
        }
      },
      {
        "my_api": {
          "label": "Last name",
          "value": [
            "Jackson"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "my_api": {
          "label": "Favourite colour",
          "value": "I don't have any"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is my `model.py` so far:

```
class DictParameter(BaseModel): # pylint: disable=R0903
    """
    `my_api` children
    """
    label: Optional[str]
    value: Optional[str]


class DataParameter(BaseModel): # pylint: disable=R0903
    """
    `data` children
    """
    my_api: Optional[dict]  # NOTE: Future readers, this incorrect reference is part of the OP's Q


class InputParameter(BaseModel): # pylint: disable=R0903
    """
    Takes predefined params
    """
    data: Optional[List[DataParameter]]
```

In `main.py`:

```
from model import InputParameter

@router.post("/v2/workflow", status_code=200)
def get_parameter(user_input: InputParameter):
    """
    Version 2 : No decoding & retrieve workflow params
    """
    data = user_input.data

    print(data)
```

Output:

```
[DataParameter(my_api={'label': 'First name', 'value': 'Micheal'}), DataParameter(my_api={'label': 'Last name', 'value': ['Jackson']}), DataParameter(my_api={'label': 'Favourite colour', 'value': "I don't have any"})]
```

I want to access the value inside `my_api` key. But I keep getting type error. I'm not sure how to access List of dictionary with nested child. Plus, the value of `value` can be `str` or `array`. It is dynamic.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

> Plus, the value of value can be str or array. It is dynamic.

What you currently have will cast single element lists to strs, which is probably what you want.  If you want lists to stay as lists, use:

```
from Typing import Union

class DictParameter(BaseModel):
    Value: Union[str, list[str]]
```

Unless you have the good luck to be running python 3.10, on which case `str | list[str]` is equivalent.

However, you do not actually use this model!  You have `my_api: Optional[dict]` not `my_api: Optional[DictParameter]`, so your current output is a plain old dict, and you need to do `data[0].my_api["value"]`.  Currently this returns a str or a list, which is probably the problem.  I suspect, though, that you meant to use the pydantic schema.

Note that data is a list: if you want all the values you need to iterate, something like

```
apis = [x.my_api for x in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fix the issue in `DictParameter` (as pointed out by other answer by @2e0byo):

```
class DictParameter(BaseModel):
    label: Optional[str]
    value: Optional[Union[str, List[str]]]
```

And you fix the issue in `DataParameter`:

```
class DataParameter(BaseModel):
    # my_api: Optional[dict]  <-- prev value
    my_api: Optional[DictParameter]
```

You can access the values in your object the following way:

```
def get_value_from_data_param(param_obj: InputParameter, key: str):
    """
    Returns a value from an InputParameter object,
    or returns `None` if not found
    """

    # Iterate over objects
    for item in param_obj.data:

        # Skip if no value
        if not item.my_api:
            continue
        
        # This assumes there are no duplicate labels
        # if there are, perhaps make a list and append values
        if item.my_api.label == label:
            return item.my_api.value

    # If nothing is found, return None (or some `default`)
    return None
```

**Now let's test it:**

```
input_data = {
    "data": [
        {"my_api": {"label": "First name", "value": "Micheal"}},
        {"my_api": {"label": "Last name", "value": ["Jordan"]}},
        {"my_api": {"label": "Favourite colour", "value": "I don't have any"}}
    ]
}

# Create an object
input_param_obj = InputParameter.parse_obj(input_data)


# Let's see if we can get values:
f_name = get_value_from_data_param(input_param_obj, "First name")
assert f_name == 'Michael'

l_name = get_value_from_data_param(input_param_obj, "Last name")
assert l_name == ['Jordan']

nums = get_value_from_data_param(input_param_obj, "Numbers")
assert nums == ["1", "2", "3"]

erroneous = get_value_from_data_param(input_param_obj, "KEY DOES NOT EXIST")
assert erroneous == None
```